# python scripts with metasploit-framework

Tags: security, network-programming, rubygems, penetration-testing, metasploit

I have installed metasploit-framework from git. It's working fine. I have followed tutorial from [Metasploit Framework](http://blog.dinotools.de/2014/04/04/install-metasploit-from-git-on-arch/).

Now I would like to add more scripts to this framework, like scripts from [Avg Security Scripts](https://github.com/averagesecurityguy/scripts)

I would like to know, How can we install and tell metasploit to use these scripts?

Any help would be appreciated as it may help a step forward.

Answer (score 4):

Metasploit is written in Ruby and it doesn't support modules or scripts written in Python. However, Metasploit does have an RPC interface using MSGPACK.

Here are some tutorials on using Python + MSGPACK + Metasploit:

- https://www.fishnetsecurity.com/6labs/blog/scripting-metasploit-python

And here is a library that SpiderLabs put out for MSF RPC written in Python: https://github.com/SpiderLabs/msfrpc

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [guide here](https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/wiki/Loading-External-Modules).

> it's pretty easy, using Metasploit's default local module search path, $HOME/.msf4/modules, and there are just a couple caveats:
>
> - Mirror the "real" Metasploit module paths
> - Create an appropriate category

So if you're root user it is just a case of dropping in the modules into the correct directory strucutre at `/root/.msf4/modules`.